# Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder when building in Jenkins

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jenkins

A project I am working on has recently started using Jenkins 1.558 for monitoring our Java-based web application.  I added our newest version of the project to our Jenkins repository as a maven2/3 project.

The project is running with Spring 3.1.1 and Hiberate 4.2.3.  The spring-beans.xml file in our project is importing a resource file called project-dao.xml which contains all our hibernate mappings.  In that configuration file, we have a "sessionFactory" bean that uses the LocalSessionFactoryBean class:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="project-persist-dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="project-persist_hibernateProperties" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="hibernateInterceptorChain"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
<list>
</list>
```

Our project includes unit test classes that run with org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.  Our unit classes also use the org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration class to load and configure the ApplicationContext.

Here is the header of one of our test classes

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "/context/project-foundation.xml", "/context/project-dao.xml",
    "/context/project-persist-dev.xml", "/context/project-persist-utest.xml" })
public class PageDaoTest extends   AbstractProjectDaoTest<Page, Long>{
```

These tests pass when I run Maven on my laptop I use for development.  However, they fail every time I try a build in Jenkins.  The results show this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [context/project-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:259)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 44 more
```

The "Caused by" line tells me that LocalSessionFactoryBuilder class cannot be found.  Our pom file has the org.springframework.spring-orm-3.1.1.jar dependency included, which contains the LocalSessionFactoryBuilder class.

Has anyone experienced a problem like this with Spring in Jenkins?

Thanks.

Comment: drop those jars from the local maven repository used by jenkins so that they are downloaded again. They simply might be corrupted which explains why the same project works on your box.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the jenkins maven repository and removed the JAR files.  I then ran the build on Jenkins again.  The same error is occurring though, even after switching between various versions of maven.